# ¿Cómo hago para evitar que se seleccione un campo adicional que agregue a un combobox? estoy trabajando con ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Tengo la siguiente duda: estoy aprendiendo ASP MVC y estoy cargando un combobox desde la base de datos, para que ese combobox no aparesca seleccinado el primer dato le agregue otro item al combobox(--Seleccione un dato--).
si tienen una solucion con `dataannotation`, mucho mejor.

Comment: Hola @Javier , Bienvenido a [StackOverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), te recomiendo un [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por la pagina y ver [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para hacer un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y la comunidad acepte de buena forma tu pregunta

Comment: Este workshop te será de utilidad: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
class ModelCombo{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }

}
```

Cuando cargues la información en el modelo:

```
List<ModelCombo> combo = new List<ModelCombo>();

        // Add parts to the list.
        combo.Add(new ModelCombo() {id=0 , descripcion="--Seleccione un dato-" });
```

Para que tome por defecto el mensaje, luego la información que traes de la base de datos o bien desde el propio select de la base:

```
select 0 as id, "--Seleccione un dato-" as descripcion
union all
select id, descripcion from tablacombo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Si usas el helper para generar el combo, este tiene la capacidad de definir un valor cuando no hay seleccionado ningun item

```
@Html.DropDownList("List", "--Seleccione un dato--")
```

No necesitas agregar el item a los datos, simplemente defines el texto en al parametro del DropDownList helper

[How to Use DropDownList Helper in MVC Application](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/54db21/dropdownlist-helper-in-mvc/)